# Is there any mobile testing tools?

Tags: java, testing, mobile, java-me, emulation

I want to ask about a tool or software to test j2me mobile app. On
different screens and different devices.

Also if available to test if application not certified or try to steal user data

Preferred free if exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download the Emulators for testing from following sites,

[Sprint SDK](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/java_me/javame.jsp)

[Sony Ericsson SDK](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads?cc=gb&lc=en)

[Samsung SDK](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/)

<strike>[Motorola SDK](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/sdks/)</strike>   [ Link not found. ]

[Nokia SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/)

[Oracle Java ME SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/index.html)

And you can also test your application on Nokia RDA devices. see this site.

[Nokia RDA devices](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/)