# Looking for an alternative to the Motorola Java ME SDK for for platform emulator customization

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation

I'm following a tutorial that utilizes the Motorola Java ME sdk for device profile customization, as it uses quite a user-friendly UI, but this SDK seems to no longer exist. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

I'm using netbeans as my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't find any Motorola emulator for Java ME. Because they fully moved to Android. So better you can try with [some other emulator for Java ME.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748269/is-there-any-mobile-testing-tools)